# Issue with negative input values failing to print a message

Tags: python, input

I have written the following program to calculate and print the perfect squares up to a given upper bound. However I am failing to make my program print `You must enter a positive integer` when an input of anything but a positive integer (eg, negative integers or letters) is entered. How can I adjust my program so that it does this?

```
"""Print all the perfect squares from zero up to a given maximum."""
def read_bound():
   """Reads the upper bound from the standard input (keyboard).
      If the user enters something that is not a positive integer
      the function issues an error message and retries
      repeatedly"""

   line = input("Enter the upper bound: ")
   try:
       upper_bound = int(line)
   except:
       raise ValueError("You must enter a positive integer.")
   else:
       return upper_bound  


def is_perfect_square(num):
   """Return true if and only if num is a perfect square"""
   for candidate in range(1, num):
       if candidate * candidate == num:
           return True
   return False



def print_squares(upper_bound, squares):
   """Print a given list of all the squares up to a given upper bound"""
   print("The perfect squares up to {} are: ". format(upper_bound))
   for square in squares:
       print (square, end=' ')


def main():
   """Calling the functions"""
   upper_bound = read_bound()
   squares = []
   for num in range(2, upper_bound + 1):
       if is_perfect_square(num):
           squares.append(num)

   print_squares(upper_bound, squares)    


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`int` converts any string looking like an integer. Positive or negative.

So you'll never have an exception when parsing a negative value. You would have to add an explicit `raise` to to so:

```
   upper_bound = int(line)
   if upper_bound < 0:
      raise ValueError("You must enter a positive integer, got {}".format(upper_bound))
   return upper_bound # don't forget to return the value
```

in that case, you don't need to protect your statement by `try/except` (besides that being bad practice because it traps *any* exception including CTRL+C/user break) you're only doing this to throw a less accurate error message. Let your program crash properly with the stacktrace and the clean exception from integer parsing.

Comment: Hi, tried your solution and it gave me an error saying `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'`. Note that my initial solution was something pretty similar to yours (before I changed it to what it is now in my question) and it was giving the same error. If you can help me fix this issue I think my initial solution might work as well.

Comment: Oh, if you remove the try/except/else` statement don't forget to return `upper_bound`...

Answer (score 0):

Integers are whole numbers meaning they can be negative. You need a conditional. I would advise researching the functions you are using and the datatypes they return before taking time to post.